# How to properly close an Angular $modal

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have this code in my HTML invoking a modal:

`<button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="myCtrl.someModal()">{{myCtrl.title}}/button>`

The `someModal` function is this:

```
that.someModal = function() {
    var modal = $modal({
        templateUrl: 'some_template.html',
        backdrop: 'static',
        controller: "someCtrl",
        controllerAs: "sCtrl",
            resolve : {
                result : function() {
                    return {
                        cancel : function() {
                            modal.hide();
                        }
                    };
                }
            }
        });
};
```

Then there is a

```
(function(){
    var app = angular.module('myModule');
    app.controller("someCtrl", ['Restangular', 'result', function(Restangular, result) {

    that.cancel = function() {
            result.cancel();
        };
    }]);
})();
```

and finally in the modal I have:

```
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="sCtrl.cancel()">Close</button>
</div>
```

This **works**, but it seems the wrong way to do this.

Two questions:

1. How do I properly close the modal?
2. The above gives a warning at `modal.hide()` stating that `The local variable modal may not have been initialized`. How can I re-write to make the warning go away?

**Note**: The code is using `angular-strap`, not `angular-ui` (which seems to be much more popular)

Answer (score 3):

in your controller change the method to:

```
$scope.cancel = function () {
   modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
};
```

modalInstance is the reference returned by the $modal.open

doc here:
http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal

Comment: I saw this, but it uses `$uibModal` not `$modal` (which apparently are different things). Also note that my code does not have `open` anywhere. Trying to add a `modalInstance` to the controller throws an error.

Comment: Actually `$modal.open(..)` throws an error - no such method.

Comment: you should update your angular-ui-boostrap module to the latest version in order to use the new api

Comment: I edited the question. Our project uses angular-strap, not angular-ui

Answer (score 0):

Apparently for angular-strap `$hide()` is available on the scope.
Adding `data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="$hide()"` to the close button works fine.

My mistake was that I tried `hide()` as the tutorial I used said which didn't work.